# Solving exponential equation (quadratic type)

Tags: exponential-function, quadratics

I fail trying to solve the following equation:
$9^x-6^x-2^{2x+1}=0$

Trying to write it as a quadratic equation makes my constant term exponential
$(3^x)^2-2^x3^x-2^{2x+1}=0$

How can I solve this type of problem most efficiently?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

\begin{align*}
  9^x-6^x-2^{2x+1} &=0 \\
  (\color{red}{3^x})^2-(\color{red}{3^x})(\color{blue}{2^x})-
  2(\color{blue}{2^x})^2 &=0 \\
  (\color{red}{3^x}+\color{blue}{2^x})
  (\color{red}{3^x}-2\cdot \color{blue}{2^x}) &= 0
\end{align*}

Rejecting $\color{red}{3^x}+\color{blue}{2^x}=0$, we have
\begin{align*}
  \left( \frac{3}{2} \right)^{x} &= 2 \\
  x(\ln 3-\ln 2) &= \ln 2 \\
  x &= \frac{\ln 2}{\ln 3-\ln 2}
\end{align*}

Comment: How do you go from row nr2 to row nr3?, the last factoring there?

Comment: Replace $3^x$ by $a$ and $2^x$ by $b$, you have $a^2-ab-2b^2=(a+b)(a-2b)$.

Answer (score 3):

dividing by $$2^{2x}$$ we get $$\left(\frac{3^x}{2^x}\right)^2-\frac{3^x}{2^x}-2=0$$ and set $$t=\frac{3^x}{2^x}$$ and you will get an quadratic equation.